# Bash script with netcat expression in if statement

Tags: bash

I have a script I'm using to help with docker-compose orchestration called `wait_to_start.sh` that I obtained from [here](http://brunorocha.org/python/dealing-with-linked-containers-dependency-in-docker-compose.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $WAIT_COMMAND
echo $WAIT_START_CMD

is_ready() {
    eval "$WAIT_COMMAND"
}

# wait until is ready
i=0
while ! is_ready; do
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    if [ $i -ge $WAIT_LOOPS ]; then
        echo "$(date) - still not ready, giving up"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "$(date) - waiting to be ready"
    sleep $WAIT_SLEEP
done

#start the script
exec $WAIT_START_CMD
```

However, I'm having trouble getting it working. I'd like to use netcat to test the service is running.

```
couchbase:
  container_name: couchbase
  image: couchbase/server:community-3.0.1
  volumes:
    - /opt/couchbase/var:/opt/couchbase/var
  ports:
    - "8091:8091"

myapp:
  container_name: myapp
  image: myapp
  command: wait_to_start.sh
  volumes_from:
    - couchbase
  links:
    - couchbase:couchbase
  environment:
    - WAIT_COMMAND=[ `nc -z -w3 localhost 8091` -eq 0 ]
    - WAIT_START_CMD=mycmd
    - WAIT_SLEEP=2
    - WAIT_LOOPS=10
```

However it doesn't work.

When I run netcat directly on the command line it works.  It returns 0 on success.  The above doesn't work.

I was getting:

```
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
```

So I played around and found that echoing `WAIT_COMMAND` produces

```
[ -eq 0 ]
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm a bit of a bash noob.  It must be something simple.

Comment: Command substitution (the backticks) get you a command's *output* not its return code.

Comment: Ah right, because I was following the original example which used curl.

Comment: This could be simplified with just `WAIT_COMMAND="nc -z -w3 couchbase 11211"`.

Comment: Also since that script uses `eval` (which is a **horrible** thing) you can put an arbitrarily complicated command in there. And just sticking an `!` at the start of the `nc` command should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tips and comments and lots of experimentation.
What worked in the end was this:

```
[ $(nc -z -w3 couchbase 11211; echo $?) -eq 0 ]
```

I also found that if I try to set WAIT_COMMAND directly in the script to test it, it gets evaluated early.  So I had to use single quotes.

i.e.

```
WAIT_COMMAND='[ $(nc -z -w3 couchbase 11211; echo $?) -eq 0 ]'
```

In docker-compose.yml it looks like this:

```
environment:
    WAIT_COMMAND=[ $(nc -z -w3 couchbase 11211; echo $?) -eq 0 ]
```

Or simply: (thanks Etan!)

```
WAIT_COMMAND="! nc -z -w3 couchbase 11211"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
WAIT_COMMAND=[ nc -z -w3 localhost 8091 -eq 0 ]
```

simply use

```
WAIT_COMMAND="nc -z -w3 localhost 8091"
```

The `[` command is not necessary to evaluate the return code of a program.

Comment: That doesn't work.  Because nc returns zero. And the script is looking for eq to zero is an error.  I still want it to work the same way.